# How to return the json array to my view in Codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter

How can I display my data value from json to my view,  I have this result from response

```
{"data":{"agency":"Jeddah Islamic Port","num_letter":"1","lab_id":"1","id":"1","quantity":"1","sample_tyre":"Truck (tubetype)","manufacturer":"TRANSTONE","trademark":"TRANS 216","origin":"CHINA","size":"12.00R24","loadindex":"","symbol":"","ply":"20","loadkg":"","year":"2016","week":"1","notes":"","status":"1","recalling":"0","conf_res":"","rejection":"","reject_ar":"","remarks":"","need_test":"1","TypeOfRejection":"","print":"0","agencies":"Jeddah Islamic Port","package":"1","letter_date":"2017-02-23","letter_date2":"0000-00-00","recieved_date":"2017-02-23","letter_no":"1","note":"","subCustomer":"","final_result":"","conformity_date":"0000-00-00"},"image":null}
```

This is just 1 row and I want to pass the data from my input textbox

ex:

```
<input type="text" name="agency" value="Jeddah Islamic Port">

<input type="text" name="num_letter" value="1">
```

Controller:

```
$result['data'] = $this->sample_photo_model->search_sample_id();
echo json_encode($result);
```

my ajax: I'm missing something here in my ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
    success: function(data){
       $('#result').html();  //??????           
    }
});
```

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem and just $('#agency').val(data.data.agency); on my ajax and ID on my textbox

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $('#agency').val(data.data.agency); //add this line to pass the value on my textbox
    }
});

//I add ID on my textbox
<input type="text" name="agency" id="agency" value="Jeddah Islamic Port">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by changing header..

```
header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
$result['data'] = $this->sample_photo_model->search_sample_id();
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: but how to pass to my view?

Comment: json encode will pass your  data.. you can check using alert in success function

Comment: yea its passing the data from response and I'm getting alert of my data. But the problem is how to pass it to my view.  Inside of the textbox.

Comment: set id="agency" in text box and write this code in success function.
$("#agency").val(data['agency']);

Comment: I solve it my adding this line $('#agency').val(data.data.agency); this is I'm missing and also the ID